# Keep x number of directories and delete all others, need to exclude one directory and its contents every time

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete all but the 10 most recent directories, always excluding the java directory.  Unfortunately it is deleting all but the last 10 the contents of the "java" directory too.

I've been trying to modify the solution from the following link to get my situation to work properly:
[Keep x number of files and delete all others - PART TWO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914763/keep-x-number-of-files-and-delete-all-others-part-two)

The directory structure is as follows:

```
dev_app_backup\java
dev_app_backup\2012-05-09_01-00-05_commnXsl  (contains Xsl files)
dev_app_backup\2012-05-09_01-00-05_published  (contains zip files)
dev_app_backup\various-dates-time_commonXsl
dev_app_backup\various-dates-time_published
```

My plan is to run a second script to clean out the java subdirectories.

```
#----- define folder where files are located ----#
$TargetFolder = "\\test\TestShare\dev_app_backup\*"

#----- number of directories to keep ----#
$keep = 10

#----- get zip files based on lastwrite filter ---#
$files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -recurse -exclude java

if ($files.Count -gt $keep) 
{
$files | Sort-Object -property $_.LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so this is the script I came up with, sorry, this is my first powershell script...

```
$TargetFolder = "\test\TestShare\dev_app_backup*"
$keep = 10
$folders = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -exclude java*
echo "folders"
echo $folders
echo "endfolders"
echo $folders.Count
echo $folders | Sort-Object -property $_.LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First ($folders.Count - $keep)
foreach ($folder in $folders | Sort-Object -property $_.LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First ($folders.Count - $keep))
{
echo $folder
$files = Get-Childitem $folder -recurse
echo $files
Remove-Item -Force $folder\$files
Remove-Item -Force $folder
}
```

The echoes are just there to help me debug, feel free to remove them.

Comment: I have 13 top level directories, one of which is the java directory.  it deleted all of the contents of the other 12 directories. :(

Comment: the only problem I'm running into is that the script is asking to confirm the deletion.

Comment: Strange, I wasn't getting asked for confirmation after I put in this line `Remove-Item -Force $folder\$files`

Comment: Jgritty- did you remove the line below $folder\$files?  Remove-Item -Force $folder

Comment: No, it's still there.  Did removing it fix a problem?  If I take it out, I assume it'll leave empty folders behind.

Comment: no that didn't seem to help, I # out the echo statements.  I didn't notice the following error before the first confirm question, "Remove-Item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Comment: Also getting the following, "Remove-Item : Cannot find path '\test\TestShare\dev_app_backup\2012-04-18_13-24-12_commonXsl\worksheet_cas.xml worksheet_cas.xsl' because it does not exist."

Comment: I wonder if you are actually over the 248/260 character limit.  That's a limit in Windows itself.  I think it only applies to certain APIs, I think, but apparently powershell is using one.  It's strange because it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I counted the longest path name at 142 characters in test, but production would be 301 characters.

Comment: Any idea how to get rid of this?                                  Confirm
The item at Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\servername\sharename\z-test\Dev_app_backup\test7 - Copy (2) -
Copy has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the
item. Are you sure you want to continue?  and there is the -Force parameter...Remove-Item $folder\$files -Force
Remove-Item $folder -Force

Comment: The following changes work, now to figure out how to email if only 10 folders exist.<br/>$files = Get-Childitem $folder<br/>  Remove-Item $folder\$files -Force -Recurse<br/>
Remove-Item $folder -Force -Recurse